# "К каким часам приехать?" — можно ли так писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, фразеология

Мне часто пишут: "К каким часам приехать?" По моему мнению, если речь идёт не о часах, как о предмете, а о времени, то это ошибка. Права ли я?

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке устоявшийся вариант вопроса таков: **к которому часу?**
Теоретически не противоречит нормам языка вопрос *к которым часам?*, если имеются в виду два или более приезда: "К которым часам мне приехать?" -- "Приезжай к девяти, потом к шестнадцати".
Но поскольку *к которому часу?* именно устоявшееся выражение, а слово "часы" имеет ещё значение прибора для определения времени, то вариант *к которым часам?* (и тем более *к каким часам?*), я думаю, следует считать некорректным.

Answer (score 2):

1. Как выбрать форму вопроса

***Во сколько приезжать?*** Но точное указание времени не требуется, минуты считать никто не будет.

***В котором часу?*** Книжное слово ***который*** из разговорной речи активно вытесняется. *Сколько времени, который час* — оба варианта нормативны.

***К скольким часам?***  Это уже лучше. ***К пяти часам*** подъезжай. Но вот фонетика здесь неудобная, стечение согласных КСК. В результате получается — ***к каким часам?***  Но всё это пока не нормировано.

2. В Нацкорпусе можно встреть такую фразу:  *А. Т. молча выслушивал приглашение, переспрашивал иногда, когда **и к какому часу,** потом говорил: «Хорошо, буду» ― и вешал трубку.* [И. А. Дедков. Дневник (1983)]

"***К какому часу***" уже допускает некоторую неопределенность во времени, но не очень значительную . В то же время  предложение "*К каким часам собираемся*?" подразумевает более широкий и свободный интервал времени, например "примерно часам к пяти или пяти-шести".

**P. S.** Вообще говоря, наше время напоминает мне отчасти эпоху Возрождения. Странно звучит, и не все согласятся, но я имею в виду **раскованность и свободу мышления.**

Несомненно, правила должны **регулировать** нашу речь, но не должны **сдерживать ее развитие** искусственными рамками и канонами. И язык правилен тогда, когда он удобен для пользователей и в произношении, и в грамматике, и в выражении нужного смыслового значения.